# How to add google test executable to SConstruct file

Tags: c++, googletest, scons, godot

Edit: After trying to get it to work for a day, I just re-wrote it in cmake. Scons is not actually required in any way to work with godot native.

I have a godot project with some native (c++) scripts. I would like to add google-test unit tests for the c++ classes.

scons is completely new to me and I am having a hard time groking the documentation. With the existing SConstruct file, how can I add a new google test target that uses the source files in my `native/test` directories (multiple layers of subdirectories), and links against my existing library?

I would like to use VariantDir to keep the object files out of the test source directories.

The test target lines are near the bottom, I included the whole file for context.

```
#!python
import os, subprocess

opts = Variables([], ARGUMENTS)

projectName = 'mygame'
projectPrettyName = 'MyGame'

# Gets the standard flags CC, CCX, etc.
env = DefaultEnvironment()

# compilation database support
env.Tool("compilation_db")
env.Alias("compiledb", env.CompilationDatabase('compile_commands.json'))

# Define our options
opts.Add(EnumVariable('target', "Compilation target", 'debug', ['d', 'debug', 'r', 'release']))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('platform', "Compilation platform", 'linux', ['', 'windows', 'x11', 'linux', 'osx']))
opts.Add(EnumVariable('p', "Compilation target, alias for 'platform'", 'linux', ['', 'windows', 'x11', 'linux', 'osx']))
opts.Add(BoolVariable('use_llvm', "Use the LLVM / Clang compiler", 'yes'))
opts.Add(PathVariable('target_path', 'The path where the lib is installed.', projectName + '.godot/bin/'))
opts.Add(PathVariable('target_name', 'The library name.', 'lib' + projectName, PathVariable.PathAccept))

# Local dependency paths, adapt them to your setup
godot_headers_path = "godot-cpp/godot_headers/"
cpp_bindings_path = "godot-cpp/"
cpp_library = "libgodot-cpp"

# only support 64 at this time..
bits = 64

# Updates the environment with the option variables.
opts.Update(env)

# Process some arguments
if env['use_llvm']:
    env['CC'] = 'clang'
    env['CXX'] = 'clang++'

if env['p'] != '':
    env['platform'] = env['p']

if env['platform'] == '':
    print("No valid target platform selected.")
    quit();

# Check our platform specifics
if env['platform'] == "osx":
    env['target_path'] += 'osx/'
    cpp_library += '.osx'
    if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-g', '-O2', '-arch', 'x86_64'])
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-arch', 'x86_64'])
    else:
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-g', '-O3', '-arch', 'x86_64'])
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-arch', 'x86_64'])

elif env['platform'] in ('x11', 'linux'):
    env['target_path'] += 'x11/'
    cpp_library += '.linux'
    if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-fPIC', '-g3', '-Og'])
        env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++17'])
    else:
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-fPIC', '-g', '-O3'])
        env.Append(CXXFLAGS=['-std=c++17'])

elif env['platform'] == "windows":
    env['target_path'] += 'win64/'
    cpp_library += '.windows'
    # This makes sure to keep the session environment variables on windows,
    # that way you can run scons in a vs 2017 prompt and it will find all the required tools
    env.Append(ENV=os.environ)

    env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['WIN32', '_WIN32', '_WINDOWS', '_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS'])
    env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-W3', '-GR'])
    if env['target'] in ('debug', 'd'):
        env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['_DEBUG'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-EHsc', '-MDd', '-ZI'])
        env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-DEBUG'])
    else:
        env.Append(CPPDEFINES=['NDEBUG'])
        env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-O2', '-EHsc', '-MD'])

if env['target'] in ('release', 'r'):
    cpp_library += '.release'
else:
    cpp_library += '.debug'

cpp_library += '.' + str(bits)

# make sure our binding library is properly includes
env.Append(CPPPATH=['.', godot_headers_path, cpp_bindings_path + 'include/', cpp_bindings_path + 'include/core/', cpp_bindings_path + 'include/gen/'])
env.Append(LIBPATH=[cpp_bindings_path + 'bin/'])
env.Append(LIBS=[cpp_library])

env.Append(CPPPATH=['native/include/'])
env.VariantDir('#build/', 'native/src', duplicate=0)
sources = Glob('#build/**.cpp')

libPath = target=env['target_path'] + env['target_name']
library = env.SharedLibrary(libPath, source=sources)

# Test target description: Help needed here
env.VariantDir('#tbuild/', 'native/test', duplicate=0) # ???
testsources = Glob('#tbuild/*cpp') # ???
tests = env.Program(???)

Default(library, 'compiledb')
```

Comment: Did you create this whole SConscipt? Why use DefaultEnvironment()?  How many levels of directories are under native/test? are the sources there generated by other logic, or static (not machine generated)?

Comment: @bdbaddog, it is a slightly modified version of the SConscript that comes with the godot example c++ project. Why not use DefaultEnvironment? There will be multiple levels of directories under native/test, they will match the directory tree under my native/src. Sorry if these are obvious questions, I am quite familiar with make and cmake but can't seem to wrap my head around scons

Comment: Are any of the files under native/test generated by build logic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how we use google test.  We added a SConscript file where the program code is located. THe SConsctruct is calling that sconscript.:

```
env.USE_GTEST()
env.Append(LIBS = libraries)

#Creates the binary
prg = env.buildProgram('ts_test', ['ts_test.cpp'])
Alias('but', prg)

# Execute the test seting the resulting XML as a target.
# Note how using the previous target as source means that test will ONLY RUN if the source has changed
# and if it's source changed, and so on. So a unit-test will not run if it's tested code did not change.

# OPTIONS: Change test execution options here. Do "--help" on your unit-test binary for a complete list.
# Example: Use this to run 10 times only tests with name that starts with 'memory'.
#   testOptions = ' --gtest_repeat=10 --gtest_filter=memory*
testOptions = ' --gtest_color=yes'

Alias('rut', env.Command(target = 'unit_test_result.xml', 
                          source = prg, 
                          action = [ 'cd ' + env.getStripCwd()  + ';' + os.path.join(env['LOCALROOT'],'$SOURCE') + testOptions + ' --gtest_output=xml:' + os.path.join(env['LOCALROOT'],'$TARGET')] ) )

def USE_GTEST(env):
    gtestRoot = get_third_party_root(env, 'GTEST_ROOT')
    incDir = os.path.join(gtestRoot, 'include')
    libs = []

    if env['PLATFORM'] == 'posix':
        libDir = os.path.join(gtestRoot, 'lib')
        libs.append('gtest')
        libs.append('gtest_main')   
        libs.append('pthread')
    else: # Windows
        libDir = os.path.join(gtestRoot, 'msvc', '2010', 'gtest-md')    

        if isDebug(env):
            libs.append('gtestd')
            libs.append('gtest_maind')   
            if env['CONFIG'] == 'win32':
                libDir = os.path.join(libDir, 'Win32-Debug')
            else:
                libDir = os.path.join(libDir, 'x64-Debug')
        else:
            libs.append('gtest')
            libs.append('gtest_main')   
            if env['CONFIG'] == 'win32':
                libDir = os.path.join(libDir, 'Win32-Release')
            else:
                libDir = os.path.join(libDir, 'x64-Release')

    env.Append(CPPPATH = [incDir],
               LIBPATH = [libDir],
               LIBS = libs)
```